# Cloudinary - able to console.log to retrieve URL but unable to save URL to a state in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I am making a clothing application that involves a parameter of a user uploading an image and I am trying to save that image in a state variable in React. I am able to console.log the response url but no matter how I try to save that url in a state, it keeps coming back as null/undefined.

I've tried placing the setClothing state to save the URLs in many different areas in hopes that it is due to asynchronous behaviour but have not been successful. My console.log in my axios.post request successfully displays the correct URL no matter how many images I upload at once but I am unable to save it

This is my code:

```
const [clothing, setClothing] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    category: "",
    location: "",
    price: 0,
    images: [],
    userOwner: userID,
});

const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const fileInput = Array.from(form.elements).find(({ name }) => name === 'file');


    const responses = await Promise.all(
        Array.from(fileInput.files).map(async (file) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.UPLOAD_PRESET);

            axios.post(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload`, formData)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.secure_url);
                
                setClothing(prevClothing => ({
                        ...prevClothing,
                        images: [...prevClothing.images, response.data.secure_url]
                    }));
            })          
        })
    );
        return responses
}
```

I'm including some of my other code in case that helps:
Model:

```
const ClothingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String,},
    description: {type: String,},
    category: {type: String,},
    location: {type: String,},
    price: {type: Number,min: 0,},
    images: [{type: String,},] ,
    reviewIds: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "review",},],
    userOwner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "users",required: true}})
```

Comment: It is related to the asynchronous behavior of the `axios.post` requests. Since you're using `Promise.all`, you're correctly waiting for all the requests to complete, but you're not properly handling the responses and updating the state within the `map` function. The `setClothing` function should be called after all the promises are resolved.